# UIPasteboard After Copying Gif Not Displaying Paste Option

Tags: objective-c, uipasteboard

I am making a custom keyboard with buttons that copy gifs.  I have used this code:

```
@import MobileCoreServices;

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs37/f/2008/283/a/b/KaleidoCoils_animated__gif_by_1389AD.gif"]];
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard=[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeGIF];
```

I believe that it is the right code, but when I go to paste the image, I am not able to.  I have used the same code on my mainstoryboard and it works, I am able to paste the image.  Is there any settings in my info.plist I need to change that my mainstoryboard may have in order for my custom keyboard to be able to copy gifs?  Any help at all is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that `data` isn't `nil`?

Comment: How exactly would I go around doing that because I think your right.  If you are right what might be not allowing the gif to be copied?

Comment: Is there anyone who possibly knows any things I need to add to my info.plist in order to allow gifs to be copied/pasted via a storyboard that is not the main storyboard?